# 1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'db'

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I tried a lot to import the sql script to create database and tables through phpmyadmin in the new site I hosted. But I'm getting the error,

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'db'

I tried to create a sample db directly : `create database sampled;` I'm getting the same access denied error.

I'm not able to grant privileges to the user also, I'm getting the same access denied error.

Following is the output of show grants command.

```
show grants;
GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'somepw' 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON someuser\_%.* TO 'someuser'@'localhost'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` ?

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Godaddy then **don't** directly go to phpMyAdmin and run the sql command.

You have to go to **MySQL® Databases** section and create a database there. 
Then **create a user** and give it the **permission** to access the database you just created.
Now you can go to **phpMyAdmin** and write your SQL commands.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

This error can be avoided in the beginning when creating the `user account`. Following commands must be used to create `user account` having all the `PRIVILEDGES`.

```
CREATE USER 'demouser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '***';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'demouser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

ALTER USER 'demouser'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'demouser';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `demouser`.* TO 'demouser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: in addition to what "Mahmoud Abbas" said... you need to login to mysql as root using **sudo mysql --user=root** and then checkout the privileges with `SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;`

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that the user `someuser` do not have proper privilege over the database `db`. You need to grant privileges for the user over the database to correct this issue.

If you do bot have administrative rights contact your admin for granting privileges to `someuser` on that `db`

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem is I'm not having permissions to create new Database name or even modify the name of the Database. You can contact your admin to avail priviledges or if you want to quickly import the `.sql` file... then you can open the .sql file with text editor and find the following line:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `enter the existing db name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `enter the existing db name`;
```

After that try to import the `.sql` file. Now you can successfully import all the tables!

Answer (score 1):

Must Ensure that your User_Name, Password and Database name are correct.
If you are Deal with database 'sampled' then type 'sampled' in query instead of 'db' also must ensure that you don't have to use quota(') in Statement.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by change the GRANTEE and made the user priviledges to do all the operation in PhpMyAdmin ,follow the steps :

1. Enter to mysql in root permission but :

   sudo mysql
   Enter the password, and type this :

   SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
   And see the user in IS_GRANTABLE is yes or no.
   If yes, then see the PRIVILEGE_TYPE what it might it be just tow operation if it's true, add the last operations.
   and see this [link](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/mysql/how-create-mysql-user-and-grant-permissions-command-line) to change IS_GRANTABLE from no to yes.
   I wish this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have not exported database from localhost or from web server correctly follow these steps go to localhost database click export tab than select 'Custom - display all possible options 'check box few options will open in section 'output' change compression none to zipped and now click go button at bottom it will properly export your database you can now import to hosting or anywhere you want with no errors

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error message for no reason at all. Solved by using MySQL and the `Server menu option;` Selected my `bitnami_wordpress schema;` selected the `bn_wordpress user;` then picked the `Administrative Roles` tab and granted access to this user. I had to do this to all of the users that the access was removed from.