# im getting this error message when importing joomla database. im using joomla 3.1.1 on wamp serve

Tags: mysql

Error
SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `autotrad`
-- 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `autotrad` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'autotrad'@'localhost' to database 'autotrad'

Comment: The `autotrad` user has `CREATE` permission in `MySQL`?

Comment: @Lucas Henrique, yes autotrad has create permission in MySQL

Comment: @Lucas Henrique, how do i do that, im new to MySQL?

Comment: In phpmyadmin, try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'autotrad'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and after `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: I got this error                                                                      Error
SQL query:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'autotrad'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1045 - Access denied for user 'autotrad'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: So you do not have permission. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447790/1044-access-denied-for-user-userlocalhost-to-database-db